# Flutter injectible only factory methods can have parameters

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, flutter-moor

So I'm trying to use moor to create an encrypted database, and use Injectible/GetIt to be able to inject it into other classes.

I have a wrapper class

```
@Singleton.lazy(signalsReady: true)
class BillingDatabaseModule {
  static BillingDatabase _billingDatabase;

  BillingDatabase get billingDatabase => _billingDatabase;

  @factoryMethod
  static  BillingDatabaseModule billingDatabaseInit(@factoryParam String code) {
    var instance = BillingDatabaseModule();
    _billingDatabase = BillingDatabase(code);
    GetIt.instance.signalReady(instance);
    return instance;
  }
}
```

This is causing the folowing error

```
Injectable Generator ---------------------------------------------------
Error generating [BillingDatabaseModule]! only factories can have parameters
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my problem is I can't open the database until the pin is entered/created since it's the password to the database. So I'm trying to delay opening it until I've created/entred the pin.

My backup option is to create a strong random string and store it using secure storage. I mean I'm already doing that for the pin anyways.

Comment: In singleton/lazy singleton, you have to pass the argument as a module.

Comment: @RafsanUddinBegRizan could you point me to an example of how to do so?